# Vendor Prefixes in Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, blink, vendor-prefix

Since Chrome and Opera are switching to "Blink," are they changing the CSS vendor prefixes they use? Right now, Opera uses `-o-` and Chrome uses `-webkit-`. In the future, should I include something like `-blink-`, or will they remain unchanged?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blink will not use vendor prefixes. Instead you'll need to enable experimental features in the browser configuration.

See:
http://www.chromium.org/blink#vendor-prefixes
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/04/blink.html

Mozilla (Firefox) are doing something similar too: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2012OctDec/0731.html

Comment: Interesting. Hopefully this is only true for more experimental stuff, and not basic things like CSS3 transitions. Thanks for the information.

Comment: To be precise, Blink will be retaining any leftover `-webkit-` prefixes from the initial fork and gradually phasing those out, while not introducing any new ones at all.

Comment: @Rev the existing prefixes will remain in place and slowly be phased out, so only future experimental features will be behind the about flag.

Answer (score 1):

Blink is just a fork of WebKit in any case, so even if prefixes were not being phased out, newer versions of Chrome and Opera would still use the `-webkit-` prefix anyway. You would have already covered it. :)